# Background Location - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, geolocation, latitude-longitude

I have developed an application in  flutter to capture the coordinates. code below is  capturing coordinates correctly but the problem is, it is not working when the application is closed. I need to capture the location even the app is closed.Any help will be appreciated

```
@override
void initState() 
{
 super.initState( );
 BackgroundLocation.startLocationService( );
 BackgroundLocation.getLocationUpdates( (location) async {
  setState( () {
    debugPrint(globals.sUserCode);
    debugPrint(globals.sActiveTripCode);
    this.latitude = location.latitude.toString( );
    this.longitude = location.longitude.toString( );
    this.accuracy = location.accuracy.toString( );
    this.altitude = location.altitude.toString( );
    this.bearing = location.bearing.toString( );
    this.speed = location.speed.toString( );
    this.time =
        DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch( location.time.toInt( ) )
            .toString( );
  } );
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

I used such a [package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_geolocation) in the project. But the package has a certain limitation. Paid for extra use. We tried all the ways you did. But it didn't happen. Either you have to write from scratch by ios and android. otherwise, you may have no other choice. We had no other choice but to buy this package because our time was limited. And it works just fine.

Comment: Does the package allows the location tracking to run in background when the app is closed? And does it work on both iOS and Android?v

Answer (score 2):

When your app is closed, the UI Isolate isn't running.  You need to move your geo stuff to a second Isolate so it can continue to run.  See what Google has to say about that: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/background-processes

Answer (score 1):

You can also consider [this plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/radar_flutter_plugin) which has a pretty generous free tier and additional geo APIs and tracking functionality included.